# How do you count number of characters from each lines then add them all up?

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have given a question to write a function "that returns a count of the number of characters in the file whose name is given as a parameter."

So if a file called "data.txt" contains "Hi there!" and is printed by using my codes from below, it will return value of 10. (which is correct)

```
"""Attemping Question 7.
   Author: Ark
   Date: 28/04/2015
"""

def file_size(filename):
"""extracts word from a line"""
filename = open(filename, 'r')
for line in filename:
    result = len(line) #count number of characters in a line.
    return result
```

However, let say I have made another file called "data2.txt" and it contains

```
EEEEE
DDDD
CCC
BB
A
```

If I print this out it would give the value of 6. So, my challenge starts here.. what can I do with my coding to read the lines and add them all up?

print(file_size("data2.txt"))

expected 16 words (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **sum** the lengths of the lines, right now you return the length of the very first line.

Also, you must strip a trailing newline if it's there. This should work:

```
def character_count(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return sum(len(line.rstrip("\n")) for line in f)
```